# Routing all paths to one handler function at Falcon Framework

Tags: python, falconframework

I want to routes all paths that start with something like “/api” to same handler function.

Such as:

```
/api/foo
/api/bar
/api/foo/bar
/api/bar/baz/this/that
```

All should be handled with one function and I should be able to get the full path after /api.

This feature is very handy and I used it often at Node.js Express framework. Now I am looking for ways to accomplish the same thing with Python Falcon framework.

More info can be found here; It defines the feature as "white-listed “global” functionality."

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to handle all requests before they get routed to appropriate resources, I suggest you to look into [middleware components](https://falcon.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/middleware.html).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are looking for Falcon's sink facility, e.g.:

```
class Sink(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.body = ('\nTwo things awe me most, the starry sky '
                     'above me and the moral law within me.\n'
                     '\n'
                     '    ~ Immanuel Kant\n\n')

app = falcon.API()
handler = Sink().on_get
app.add_sink(handler, prefix='/')
```

This will route all URLs to the sink handler.

Comment: Can we do this without adding handlere (In this case "on_get")

            
`app = falcon.API()
handler = Sink()
app.add_sink(handler, prefix='/')
`